# The previous marker of changed input field doesn't disappear in Google Places Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, google-maps, autocomplete, google-maps-markers, google-places-api

**Hi i'm using Google Places Autocomplete with 4 inputs. The problem is that when a single input field is changed the previous marker(and its infowindow) of this input field doesn't disappear from the map. How can I make the markers to be overwritten?  Any answer is appreciated.**

**Here is my code:**

```
<script>
var map = null;
          var autocompleteOptions = {
           componentRestrictions: {country: "az"}
          };
```

**Here are the arrays for markers and infowindows:**

```
var infowindow = [];
var marker = [];
```

**setupAutocomplete function is called for every input field:**

```
function setupAutocomplete(autocomplete,inputs,i) {
            autocomplete[i] = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(inputs[i], autocompleteOptions);
            autocomplete[i].bindTo('bounds', map);

            google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete[i], 'place_changed', function() {
              infowindow[i] = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
              marker[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map
              });  
              infowindow[i].close();
              marker[i].setVisible(false);
              var place = autocomplete[i].getPlace();
              if (!place.geometry) {
                return;
              }

              // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
              if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
              } else {
                map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
                map.setZoom(17);  // Why 17? Because it looks good.
              }

              marker[i].setIcon(/** @type {google.maps.Icon} */({
                url: place.icon,
                size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
                origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
                scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 35)
              }));
              marker[i].setPosition(place.geometry.location);
              marker[i].setVisible(true);

              var address = '';
              if (place.address_components) {
                address = [
                  (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
                  (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
                  (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
                ].join(' ');
              }

              infowindow[i].setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' + address);
              infowindow[i].open(map, marker[i]);
            });
}
        function initialize() {
          var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.4700, 49.9600),
            zoom: 10,
            zoomControl:true,
            zoomControlOptions: {
              style:google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
            },
            mapTypeControl:true,
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
              style:google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU 
            }
          };
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
            mapOptions);
          var types = document.getElementById('type-selector');
          map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(types);


          var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("controlsInput");
          var autocomplete = [];
          for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {  
           setupAutocomplete(autocomplete,inputs,i);
          }
          // Sets a listener on a radio button to change the filter type on Places
          // Autocomplete.
          function setupClickListener(id, types) {
            var radioButton = document.getElementById(id);
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(radioButton, 'click', function() {
              for (var i=0 ; i<autocomplete.length; i++) {
                autocomplete[i].setTypes(types);
              }
            });
          }

          setupClickListener('changetype-all', []);
          setupClickListener('changetype-establishment', ['establishment']);
          setupClickListener('changetype-geocode', ['geocode']);
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

        </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="pac-input" class="controlsInput" type="text" placeholder="Enter the pickup point"><br>
    <input id="pac-input2" class="controlsInput" type="text" placeholder="Enter your destination"><br>
    <input id="pac-input3" class="controlsInput" type="text" placeholder="Enter your destination"><br>
    <input id="pac-input4" class="controlsInput" type="text" placeholder="Enter your destination"><br><br>

    <div hidden="hidden" id="type-selector" class="controls">
      <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-all" checked="checked">
      <label for="changetype-all">All</label>

      <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-establishment">
      <label for="changetype-establishment">Establishments</label>

      <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-geocode">
      <label for="changetype-geocode">Geocodes</label>
    </div>
    <div id="map-canvas" style="width:600px;height:380px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing Markers In google Maps Places Services](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19424002/removing-markers-in-google-maps-places-services)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check to see if the marker exists, if it does, hide it (set map to null), then delete it, before creating a new one (or you could move it and change the icon).

```
          if (marker[i] && marker[i].setMap) {
             marker[i].setMap(null);
             marker[i] = null;
          }
          marker[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map
          });
```

Full code (modified from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21335716/why-only-the-marker-of-the-last-input-appears-in-google-places-autocomplete)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
          <head>
            <title>Place Autocomplete</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
            <meta charset="utf-8">

            <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&amp;sensor=false&amp;libraries=places"></script>

<script>
var map = null;
var marker = [];
var autocomplete = [];

          var autocompleteOptions = {
           componentRestrictions: {country: "az"}
          };

function setupAutocomplete(autocomplete,inputs,i) {

        autocomplete[i] = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(inputs[i], autocompleteOptions);
        autocomplete[i].bindTo('bounds', map);

        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete[i], 'place_changed', function() {
          var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
          if (marker[i] && marker[i].setMap) {
             marker[i].setMap(null);
             marker[i] = null;
          }
          marker[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map
          });  
          infowindow.close();
          marker[i].setVisible(false);
          var place = autocomplete[i].getPlace();
          if (!place.geometry) {
            return;
          }

          // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
          if (place.geometry.viewport) {
            map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
          } else {
            map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
            map.setZoom(17);  // Why 17? Because it looks good.
          }

          marker[i].setIcon(/** @type {google.maps.Icon} */({
            url: place.icon,
            size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
            origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 35)
          }));
          marker[i].setPosition(place.geometry.location);
          marker[i].setVisible(true);

          var address = '';
          if (place.address_components) {
            address = [
              (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
              (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
              (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
            ].join(' ');
          }

          infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' + address);
          infowindow.open(map, marker[i]);
        });
    }
    function initialize() {
      var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.4700, 49.9600),
        zoom: 10,
        zoomControl:true,
        zoomControlOptions: {
          style:google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
        },
        mapTypeControl:true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
          style:google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU 
        }
      };
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
        mapOptions);
      var types = document.getElementById('type-selector');
      map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(types);


      var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("controlsInput");
      for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {  
       setupAutocomplete(autocomplete,inputs,i);
      }
      // Sets a listener on a radio button to change the filter type on Places
      // Autocomplete.
      function setupClickListener(id, types) {
        var radioButton = document.getElementById(id);
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(radioButton, 'click', function() {
          for (var i=0 ; i<autocomplete.length; i++) {
            autocomplete[i].setTypes(types);
          }
        });
      }

      setupClickListener('changetype-all', []);
      setupClickListener('changetype-establishment', ['establishment']);
      setupClickListener('changetype-geocode', ['geocode']);
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

        </script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <input id="pac-input" class="controlsInput" type="text" placeholder="Enter the pickup point"><br>
        <input id="pac-input2" class="controlsInput" type="text" placeholder="Enter your destination"><br>
        <input id="pac-input3" class="controlsInput" type="text" placeholder="Enter your destination"><br>
        <input id="pac-input4" class="controlsInput" type="text" placeholder="Enter your destination"><br><br>

        <div hidden="hidden" id="type-selector" class="controls">
          <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-all" checked="checked">
          <label for="changetype-all">All</label>

          <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-establishment">
          <label for="changetype-establishment">Establishments</label>

          <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-geocode">
          <label for="changetype-geocode">Geocodes</label>
        </div>
        <div id="map-canvas" style="width: 600px; height: 380px; "></div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_mutlipleAutocompleteB.html)